# Чтение базы Sqlite при открытом браузере

Tags: c#, sqlite

Подскажите, можно ли достать данные ( прочитать базу ) при открытом браузере?
Есть ли какие-нибудь средства обхода?

Я могу лишь прочитать базу только когда браузер закрыт, но при открытом он не пускает.

Браузер на движке хром ( chrome, opera,yandex и.т.д )

Достаю логи при помощи: `System.SQLite.dll`

пример взял от [сюда](https://github.com/Elsensee/ChromePassDecrypter/blob/master/ChromePasswords.cs):

```
private static ChromeCredential[] GetPasswords(string pathToPasswordsFile)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(pathToPasswordsFile))
            {
                return null;
            }

            string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            File.Copy(pathToPasswordsFile, tempFile);

            ArrayList result = new ArrayList();

            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + tempFile + ";Version=3;New=True;Compress=True;"))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SQLiteCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    comm.CommandText = "SELECT origin_url, username_value, password_value FROM logins";

                    using (SQLiteDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string originUrl = (string)reader["origin_url"];
                            string username = (string)reader["username_value"];
                            string password;
                            try
                            {
                                password = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ProtectedData.Unprotect((byte[])reader["password_value"], null, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser));
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                password = "Password could not be retrieved: " + ex.Message;
                            }
                            result.Add(new ChromeCredential(originUrl, username, password));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            try
            {
                File.Delete(tempFile);
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return (ChromeCredential[])result.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Какой еще браузер? И как он может прочитать базу Sqlite? И причем здесь C# ? "... но при открытом он не пускает" куда браузер кого не пускает?

Comment: @Bulson: Поправил :)

Comment: Ха, такой же вопрос уже был пару месяцев назад. У вас выбор из двух вариантов: 1) работать только при закрытом хроме; 2) перед открытием файла сначала скопировать его во временную папку, а потом уже открывать его копию. Выбирайте.

Comment: @Bulson, А если мне необходимо прочитать одновременно несколько баз из разных источников (браузеров)? Это мне нужно каждый файл копировать в отдельные папки и от туда их чекать? Но другого выхода нет я так понял?! ))

Comment: Ну, можно скопировать все нужные файлы баз в одну удобную папку и работать с ними. По-другому нельзя, с файловой базой может одновременно работать только один поток, потому она блокируется во время работы браузера.

Comment: @Bulson, Ясно, я понял.